# Unusual sysbench results Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, sysbench

I have 2 raspberry pi's that I wanted to benchmark for load balancing purpose.

- Raspberry pi Model B v1.1 - running Raspbian Jessie
- Raspberry pi Model B+ v1.2 - running Raspbian Jessie

I installed sysbench on both systems and ran: *sysbench --num-threads=1 --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=10000 --validate run* on the first and changed --num-threads=4 on the second, as its quadcore and ran both.

The results are not at all what I expected (I obviously expected the multithreaded benchmark to severely outperform the single threaded benchmark). When I ran a the command with a single thread, performance was about the same on both systems. But when I changed the number of threads to 4 on the second Pi it still took the same amount of time, except that the per request statistics showed that the average request took about 4 times as much time. I can seem to grasp why this is.

Here are the results:

---

**Raspberry pi v1.1**
Single thread
Maximum prime number checked in CPU test: 20000

Test execution summary:

- total time:                          1325.0229s
- total number of events:              10000
- total time taken by event execution: 1324.9665

per-request statistics:

- min:                                131.00ms
- avg:                                132.50ms
- max:                                171.58ms
  approx.  95 percentile:             137.39ms

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           10000.0000/0.00
    execution time (avg/stddev):   1324.9665/0.00

---

**Raspberry pi v1.2**
Four threads
Maximum prime number checked in CPU test: 20000

Test execution summary:

- total time:                          1321.0618s
- total number of events:              10000
- total time taken by event execution: 5283.8876

per-request statistics:

- min:                                486.45ms
- avg:                                528.39ms
- max:                                591.60ms
  approx.  95 percentile:             553.98ms

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           2500.0000/0.00
    execution time (avg/stddev):   1320.9719/0.03

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Raspberry pi Model B+ v1.2" has the same CPU as "Raspberry pi Model B v1.1". Both boards are from **the first** generation of Raspberry Pi and they have 1 core CPU.

For 4 CPU you need **Raspberry Pi 2 Model B** instead of **Raspberry pi Model B+**.

Yeah, the naming is a bit confusing :(

Comment: Ah, so I did misinterpreted it. I even looked it up before I started but was probably sleeping.